# Fastlane Screenshots with Authentication

Tags: ios

I'm currently using Fastlane to capture screenshots of my application to be used in both the iOS and Android app store. My problem is that Fastlane is only able to capture the loading screen and the username/password authentication screen. Is there a way to pass credentials (possibly test creds with limited access) into Fastlane to allow it to capture other screenshots of my application? If not, what other methods could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in Fastlane docs Launch Arguments under Advanced Snapshot section https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/ I think it can help

> Launch Arguments
>
> You can provide additional arguments to your app on launch. These
>   strings will be available in your app (eg. not in the testing target)
>   through `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments`. Alternatively, use
>   user-default syntax (`-key value`) and they will be available as
>   key-value pairs in `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`.
>
> ```
> launch_arguments([
>   "-firstName Felix -lastName Krause"
> ])
>
> name.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("firstName")
> // name.text = "Felix"
> ```
>
> *snapshot* includes `-FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT YES`, which will set a temporary user default for the key `FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT`, you may use
>   this to detect when the app is run by *snapshot*.
>
> ```
> if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("FASTLANE_SNAPSHOT")
> ```
>
> {
>           // runtime check that we are in snapshot mode
>       }
>
> Specify multiple argument strings and snapshot will generate
>   screenshots for each combination of arguments, devices, and languages.
>   This is useful for comparing the same screenshots with different
>   feature flags, dynamic text sizes, and different data sets.
>
> ```
> # Snapfile for A/B Test Comparison
> launch_arguments([
>   "-secretFeatureEnabled YES",
>   "-secretFeatureEnabled NO"
> ])
> ```

Comment: Thanks Sinisa. I was definitely wrong about how Fastlane takes screenshots. It seems that for Android (which I am working on now) Fastlane "piggybacks" off of Android's UI testing to capture screenshots. iOS behaves very similarly as well.